# Why did OAuth2 committee remove 'expired_token' error code ?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, rfc

On the rfc https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12#page-40 , you can see a sentence saying "Removed 'expired_token' error code."

That is, "invalid_token" will be used for expired token cases.

Why was that? I think it was very useful for the client to distinguish an expired token and an invalid token. Without "expired_token", how can the client decide whether to refresh an access token?

Answer (score 1):

It was removed to prevent potential security leaks of information that attackers might use.

Let's say an attacker can get a copy of your Access Token by sniffing all of your network traffic. But the attacker only analyzes this information after your token has expired. If the attacker tries to make requests to your service with that token, and receives back an 'expired_token' code, they know that they are onto the right thing, and just need to get a later copy.

If the attacker, however, receives back an 'invalid_token' message, it makes it more difficult for the attacker to understand that the data they had WAS an access token (maybe it was something else?).

Furthermore, the way access / refresh tokens typically work, is something like this:

- A client needs to make an API request and has an access token and a refresh token.
- The client makes a request to the API service with their access token and gets an 'invalid_token' message.
- The client locally validates their refresh token, sees it is still valid.
- The client then submits a refresh request using their refresh token, and gets a new access token.

If the client locally validates their fresh token above, and gets an error (maybe the token expired, or something), they know they need to re-authenticate the user FRESH to receive both a new refresh AND access token.

The same is true if, when the user submits their refresh request, their refresh token is considered invalid (maybe the server-side revoked this token?).

Comment: Thank you. But as a developer I am not convinced. Its disadvantages outweight its benefits since clients do need to know what happens to the access token it passes and the risk it poses is just "ok". Hopefully "expired_token" can get back some day.